# Wacom tablet. Endless error messages in OS X systemlog

Tags: macos, driver, wacom

I am running a Wacom intuos tablet with the latest software driver v6.3.16-12 on OS X El Capitan. I have noticed endless error messages in the OS X console e.g

```
27.07.16 16:00:59,520 WacomTabletDriver[416]: handleNotification:Wacom ToolID Message
27.07.16 16:01:04,596 WacomTabletDriver[416]: handleNotification:Wacom ToolID Message
27.07.16 16:01:04,684 WacomTabletDriver[416]: handleNotification:Wacom ToolID Message
27.07.16 16:01:22,624 WacomTabletDriver[416]: handleNotification:Wacom ToolID Message
27.07.16 16:01:51,127 WacomTabletDriver[416]: handleNotification:Wacom ToolID Message
27.07.16 16:02:22,511 WacomTabletDriver[416]: handleNotification:Wacom ToolID Message
```

Here’s what I tried

- I’ve reinstalled the Wacom Driver 2 times.
- Repaired OS X system permissions
- It also happening on another Mac running OS X Yosemite

The tablet seems to be working correctly. Who else is seeing these messages? What else can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** I have completely uninstalled Wacom's tablet software *6.3.16-12* and switched back to *6.3.15*-3. Also, be sure to remove all preferences files including the following leftovers:

```
/Volumes/MacBook/Library/Internet/Plug-Ins/WacomTabletPlugin.plugin
/Volumes/MacBook/Library/PreferencePanes/WacomTablet.prefpane
/Volumes/MacBook/Library/Frameworks/WacomMultiTouch.framework
/Volumes/MacBook/System/Library/Extensions/Wacom/Tablet.kext
/Volumes/MacBook/Library/Receipts/Wacom/Tablet/Docs.txt
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Desktop/Preferences.wacomprefs
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.wacom.wacomtouch.prefs
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.wacom.wacomtablet.prefs
/Volumes/MacBook/Library/LaunchAgents/com.wacom.wacomtablet.plist
/Volumes/MacBook/private/var/db/receipts/com.wacom.TabletInstaller.plist
/Volumes/MacBook/private/var/db/receipts/com.wacom.TabletInstaller.bom
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Library/Application/Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/com.wacom.removewacomtablet.sfl
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Library/Saved/Application/State/com.wacom.RemoveWacomTablet.savedState
/Volumes/MacBook/Users/yourusername/Library/Preferences/com.wacom.RemoveWacomTablet.plist
```

I have spent hours on debugging. These error messages are definitely related to the Wacom Tablet Software update 6.3.16-12. Morever it’s related to random system crashes and [strange command click behaviors](https://superuser.com/questions/1105762/wacom-intuos-issue-clicking-on-a-app-in-os-x-dock-shows-app-in-finder-instead)!